# set value of input text in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This code is trying to set the value of an input text box when the function `restoreFromSerialize` is called inside the template helper.
It is not inserting `elementValue` in the input text box even though it's value has been verified in the browser console when `console.log(elementName+" "+elementValue);` is fired.  Thanks

```js
function restoreFromSerialize() {
  formValues.split('&').forEach(function (doc) {
    var elementName = doc.split('=')[0];
    var elementValue = doc.split('=')[1];
    if($('[name=elmentName]').attr('type') == 'radio') {
      $('[name=elementName]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      console.log(elementName+" "+elementValue);
      $('[name=elementName]').val(elementValue); //<<<<< NOT WORKING
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: you snippet is not working you are missing html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-factoring your entire code:

```
function restoreFromSerialize(formValues) {
  formValues.split('&').forEach(function (doc) {
    var splited = doc.split('=');
    var elementName  = splited[0];
    var elementValue = splited[1];
    if($('[name="'+elementName+'"]').is(':radio')) {
      $('[name="'+elementName+'"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      console.log(elementName+" "+elementValue);
      $('[name="'+elementName+'"]').val(elementValue); //<<<<< NOT WORKING
    }
  });
}
```

The reason your code was not working was, you needed to pass the variable in the selector not the string literal.